# How to implement OnInit and OnChanges on same component with type safety

Tags: typescript, angular

One of the things I like about typescript is its type safety and I use it consistently.

Typescript does not support multiple inheritance, so how can I extend an Angular 2 component class by `OnInit` and `OnChanges` at the same time?

I know that it works without declaring the inheritance but I like my code without squiggly lines.

Comment: `OnInit` and `OnChanges` are interfaces, so your components don't inherit but *implement* those interfaces. A class can implement as many interfaces as it needs.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but when I F12 them (i.e. goto definition) in WebStorm for example both are implemented as abstract classes in lifecycle_hooks.d.ts. I'm using Angular 2 RC2.

Comment: Maybe you found the Dart source https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/39ecd01b8684370666586ba35a4a12c0f109807d/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks.ts#L130 Dart doesn't have interfaces but you can use classes as interfaces and implement them like an interface.

Comment: vs https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks.ts#L121

Comment: Mmm. I didn't know that Dart uses the same file endings like typescript. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`OnInit` and `OnChanges` are not classes but interfaces, so your components don't inherit but *implement* those interfaces.

As a class can implements as many interfaces as it needs, there is no problem implementing both `OnInit` and `OnChanges` interfaces on the same component.

For example:

```
class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
}
```

For more information, have a look at [Angular Lifecycle Hooks guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).